# A have this simple code on C working on stack data structure

Tags: c, stack

Trying to test my understanding working on c stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 1000
#define EMPTY -1
#define FULL (MAX_LEN -1)

typedef struct
{
    int data[MAX_LEN];
    int top;
} stack;

void reset(stack* stk) { stk->top = EMPTY; }

void push(stack* stk, int a)
{
    stk->top++;
    stk->data[stk->top] = a;
}

int top(stack* stk)
{
    return (stk->data[stk->top]);
}

int pop(stack* stk)
{
    return (stk->data[stk->top--]);
}

int is_empty(stack* stk)
{
    return (stk->top == EMPTY);
}

int is_full(stack* stk)
{
    return (stk->top == FULL);
}

void print_array_values(int n[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", n[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    int array_back[6];
    stack stack_to_build;
    int numbers[] = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    print_array_values(numbers, 6);
    reset(&stack_to_build);

    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        push(&stack_to_build, numbers[i]);
    }

    while(!is_empty(&stack_to_build) && i < 10)
    {
        array_back[i++] = pop(&stack_to_build);
    }

    printf("reverse is:\n");
    print_array_values(array_back, 6);
    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting to get the final array filled using pop from a stack array 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4 in reverse order but getting as shown on screen shot and not sure what wrong is going on. Any help is really appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kbf2.png)

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text. Just copy and paste it, and add formatting tags to show it as preformatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a very simple error.  At this point:

```
while(!is_empty(&stack_to_build) && i < 10)
{
    array_back[i++] = pop(&stack_to_build);
}
```

The value of `i` is still `6` from the `for` loop above.  You need to reset it to `0`.

```
i = 0;
while(!is_empty(&stack_to_build) && i < 10)
{
    array_back[i++] = pop(&stack_to_build);
}
```

Comment: No commentary on the risk of buffer over-/under-flow in those `push/pop` functions?

Comment: @Fe2O3 Your commentary is adequate. :-)

Comment: it worked, thank you